# How to get specific file version from git repository using python

Tags: python, git

I have a local git repo and I'm trying to find a way to get a specific version of my xlsx file into my Python code so I can process it using pandas.

I found gitpython lib; but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

```
repo = Repo(path_to_repo)
commit = repo.commit(sha)
targetfile = commit.tree / 'dataset.xlsx'
```

I don't know what to do next.
I tried to load it to pandas using path; but, of course, it just loads my last version.

How to load previous version of xlsx to pandas?

Comment: Why not have *Git* check out the particular file and/or commit that you like (using `git checkout <commit-hash>` or `git switch --detach <hash>` for instance, or `git restore` to extract one particular file)? Then you can just use your OS's ordinary file facilities to read the file, now that it's not *in* Git any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask for `commit.tree / 'dataset.xlsx'`, you get back a `git.Blob` object:

```
>>> targetfile
<git.Blob "3137d9443f54325b8ad8a263b13053fee47fbff2">
```

If you want to read the contents of the object, you can extract the content using `data_stream` method, which returns a file-like object:

```
>>> data = targetfile.data_stream.read()
```

Or you can use the `stream_data` method (don't look at me, I didn't name them), which writes data into a file-like object:

```
>>> import io
>>> buf = io.BytesIO()
>>> targetfile.stream_data(buf)
<git.Blob "3137d9443f54325b8ad8a263b13053fee47fbff2">
>>> buf.getvalue()
b'The contents of the file...'
```